# ERROR TypeError: items.push is not a function at ShoppingCartService.addProduct

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I keep getting this error on browser whenever I'm trying to add items to Shopping-cart. Please help. Thanks`

```
      constructor() { }
      addProduct = (product) =>{ 
       let items = this.get_shopping_cart_items(); 
       if(items){
         items.push(product);
         localStorage.setItem('shopping_cart', JSON.stringify(items));
       }else
       {
         this.shopping_cart_items.push(product);
         localStorage.setItem('shopping_cart', JSON.stringify(this.get_shopping_cart_items()));      
       }
        
      }
```

This is the get function:

```
 get_shopping_cart_items =()=>{
    let items = localStorage.getItem('shopping_cart');
    if(this.IsJsonString(items)) return JSON.parse(items);
    else return {};  
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we see this line

```
let items = this.get_shopping_cart_items();
```

It seems that getter is not returning 'shopping_cart_items' property so make a getter function named 'get_shopping_cart_items' that returns the 'shopping_cart_items' property of the class like below

```
get_shopping_cart_items() {
   return this.shopping_cart_items;
}
```

this is your updated getter function

```
get_shopping_cart_items =()=>{
    let items = localStorage.getItem('shopping_cart');
    if(this.IsJsonString(items)) return JSON.parse(items);
    else return [];  
}
```

Comment: I've got the 'get_shopping_cart_items' fuction below already let me just add it to the above code

Comment: you should return [] instead of {} in else statement, see my updated answer